# Disable django-summernote widget

Tags: jquery, django, summernote

How can I disable the summernote widget used by django-summernote? I have read many similar posts in Stackoverflow, but none has solved my problem.

I tried solving it with jQuery, but nothing is returned when I use $('#summernote') or $('.summernote') from the browsers object inspector, that even if I already loaded the summernote script in the head of my html

**models.py**

```
class Note(models.Model):
    contents = models.TextField()
```

**forms.py**

```
class UpdateNoteModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['contents'].disabled = True

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ('contents')
        widgets['contents'] = SummernoteWidget()
```

**html head**

```
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
```

**html body**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){     
        $('#summernote').summernote('disable');
    });
</script >
```